# Does SwiftUI have a built-in, stack-based navigator that does not require a list layout?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want a way to have stack-based navigation in SwiftUI. Whenever I try to look up how to do that, I get information about `NavigationView`. However, it looks like `NavigationView` is intended to be used to display a list where each entry navigates to a page when tapped. Is there way to have stack-based navigation like that of `NavigationView` without having to conform to a list structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, NavigationView is used to enable navigation to other views. This can be used with any type of view. The following example will show two screens: the ContentView and the DetailView.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Main View")
                NavigationLink("Go to Detail", destination: DetailView())
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Content View")
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Detail body")
            .navigationBarTitle("Detail")
    }
}
```

If you press on the 'Go to Detail' Navigation Link, then SwiftUI pushes the `destination` view onto the screen. Pressing the back button on the detail view will pop the current view and return to the `ContentView`. You can modify the `NavigationView` with titles and buttons using some modifiers, but note that the `.navigationBarTitle()` modifier has to be used on the *inside* of the `NavigationView`, not the outside.

In summary, the NavigationView can be used with any type of view and a `List` isn't required.

Comment: When I preview this on iPad, it doesn't look at all like what I would expect if a list wasn't required. Is there a way to disable the sidebar-thing that is automatically generated by `NavigationView` and just have it render like it does on phones?

Comment: Yes, you need to specify the navigation view style. Use the `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())` modifier on `NavigationView` and it will render only the ContentView, then full-screen push the DetailView when the button is pressed.

Comment: Thank you! that's what I've been looking for this whole time, I have no idea why it was so hard to find.